# Matlab: How to plot data of a selected time range?

Tags: matlab, indexing, time

I have some data matrix, the first column is date and the second column is time.
I changed it into a table:

```
H1 = readtable(filename, 'ReadVariableNames', 0);
H1.Properties.VariableNames =...
    {'Date', 'Time', 'Value'};
t = datetime(H1.Date, 'InputFormat', 'yyyy.MM.dd');
H1.Date = t;
clear t
```

Now, I want to make a sub-table. In this table, the date of the data doesn't matter, but the time of the data must be between 18:00 and 11:00 the next day.
My time format is hh:mm (24 hours).
How could I do it? 
I think I could make another column. For each time string, I take only the first 2 characters and convert it to a number (e.g. `'05:00'` will be changed to `'05'` and then `5`). After that I could index the new column I created.
Nevertheless, I think there must be some other and easier ways to do it.
How?

In addition, if this works, I want to write a function based on this. 
I want to give a certain day and time, and plot all the data +-48 hours (or -24 hours and +72 hours) around this day and time. 
For example, if I give `'2016-06-22', '05:00'`, then I want to plot all the data ranging from `'2016-06-20', '05:00'` to `'2016-06-24', '05:00'`. Any strategy suggestion?

Given that my data size is quite big, speed is a factor that we need to take into consideration.
Thanks!

Comment: If your data is quite big, with speed as a factor, then stop using fancy data structures immediately.. and why those date time separated fields??

Comment: Probably it's not necessary to have a date column, but I might separate the date time information anyway. I could make a month column, a day of week column and a time column. I don't know which factors matter. Probably there is a correlation of time or day of week or month with the observed value. I might use some neural network to analysis my data and test my hypothesis.

Comment: Wrong!. Just a column for `t` and others for the data `x`, all numeric, nothing more!...  `datenum('2017-05-12 17:56:00')` = 736827.747222222. If really data is big and speed is a factor. If that is not, whatever you do will be ok.

Comment: Around 10 or 20 GB. There might be a seasonality, so month is important. There might also be an hourality, so time is important. Sometimes, the day-of-week might also affect the observed value. I don't know yet. So I should separate them. For the date time column (the one with all the information), I think I will keep it so that I can do calculations or create sub-tables.

Comment: If you say so....